# Trying to run Phonegap on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu, cordova, ant

I have everything ready to run Phonegap but I'm getting a error. Maybe someone know how to solve it.

**Here is the error:**

I get this error after typing **phonegap run android**

```
[apkbuilder] Creating HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/HelloWorld-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
{ [ReferenceError: a is not defined]
  stack: 'ReferenceError: a is not defined\n    at Object.ConfigParser.getPreference (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/ConfigParser.js:88:23)\n    at Object.module.exports.findOrientationPreference (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:52:26)\n    at Object.module.exports.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:84:36)\n    at Object.module.exports.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:167:18)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/prepare.js:113:31\n    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)\n    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)\n    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14\n    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)' }
Buildfile: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-a82c7d07d612c222e41d4b5fb4fa6480.jar <- /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2.2KiB) with dex B (205 defs/312.8KiB). Result is 212 defs/383.8KiB. Took 0.3s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found modified input file
[apkbuilder] Creating HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/HelloWorld-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
WARNING : No started emulators found, starting an emulator.

/home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found, if you would like to create an
 avd follow the instructions provided here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html
 Or run 'android create avd --name <name> --target <targetID>'
 in on the command line.
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
{ [ReferenceError: a is not defined]
  stack: 'ReferenceError: a is not defined\n    at Object.ConfigParser.getPreference (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/ConfigParser.js:88:23)\n    at Object.module.exports.findOrientationPreference (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:52:26)\n    at Object.module.exports.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:84:36)\n    at Object.module.exports.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/android_parser.js:167:18)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/prepare.js:113:31\n    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)\n    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)\n    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14\n    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)' }
Buildfile: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-a82c7d07d612c222e41d4b5fb4fa6480.jar <- /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2.2KiB) with dex B (205 defs/312.8KiB). Result is 212 defs/383.8KiB. Took 0.3s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found modified input file
[apkbuilder] Creating HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/HelloWorld-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds

/home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found, if you would like to create an
 avd follow the instructions provided here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html
 Or run 'android create avd --name <name> --target <targetID>'
 in on the command line.
   [error] /home/almeidamarcell/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
almeidamarcell@ubuntu:~/my-app$
```

Nodejs -**v: v0.10.26**

Node -v: **v0.11.12-pre**

npm -v: **1.4.3**

phonegap -v: **3.4.0-0.19.7**

cordova -v: **3.4.0-0.1.0**

ant -v: **Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 14 2013
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed**

Ubuntu 13.04

I also have Java and Android SDK installed.

Answer (score 5):

You can run "android" on the command line and use the GUI to select "Manage AVDs...". Create an AVD from there and you're good to go.

IMPORTANT: AVDs are only visible to the user who created it, I have to run "sudo phonegap" and tried creating an avd without sudo and it wasn't visible to phonegap. So I had to "sudo android" and create it again.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Error says:
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found, if you would like to create an
 avd follow the instructions provided here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html

You need to create a virtual device first